# Does vmWare ESXi 4.0 U1 support the Promise SuperTrak EX8650 SATA card?

Tags: vmware-esxi, raid, sas

can anyone tell me if vmWare ESXi 4.0 U1 has support for the Promise SuperTrak EX8650 SATA card?

In the hardware support guide I find that VmWare should have support for the Promise SuperTrak EX8650 SATA card but only in version ESX 3.5. Is this card not supported for ESXi 4.0 U1 or what?

From the hardware guide!
Partner Name
Model
Manufacturer
Device Type
Supported Releases
Promise SuperTrak EX8650

Promise Technology Inc SAS-RAID ESX 3.5 U5*1 1 , ESX 3.5 U4*1 1

Promise SuperTrak EX8760T
Promise Technology Inc SAS ESX / ESXi 4.0 U1*2 2 , ESX / ESXi 4.0*2 2

Answer (score 1):

This means that Promise has not delivered testing reports to VMWare on ESX 4.0 for your card.
Contact your vendor (Promise) and ask them when the card is going on the HCL.

That aside - My experience with Promise products is that they develop them, release bug fixes/firmware/drivers for a few months and then abandon the product (and release a new shiny card, like the SAS card you mention). Stay away from Promise is the best advice I can give you.

Comment: Agreed on the avoiding of Promise. Same goes for Highpoint and Adaptec.